# Do options that disable achievements in custom mode prevent progress?

Tags: dead-cells

When playing in custom mode, selecting your starting inventory and certain custom options will disable unlocking achievements during that run. Does it also prevent you from making permanent progress in those runs?

By progress I'm referring to:

- Collecting Blueprints
- Purchasing Collector Upgrades
- Upgrading the Legendary Forge
- Collecting Boss Cells

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom Mode does not stop you from making permanent progress.

You can also get achievments again, after disabling those settings in custom mode.

Comment: I am unsure if it is possible to make some achievments impossible to get though, as there are achievments where you can only do the requirement once (like "Absorb your first boss cell")

Comment: In case there are differences between versions I should probably mention that I am playing on the "Rise of the giant" update on the switch